# How can I get the content of storage and memory in my private chain?

Tags: storage, memory

I'm looking for some methods to know the content of storage and memory while the contract is running.Mayba some useful tools or abi ?

By the way, the abi of geth, debug_writeMemProfile and debug_memStats, confuse me a lot. Are they helpful?

Comment: you want to do from inside the contract or outside?

Comment: for reading stroage from outsi you can use web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, index) for memory i don't think it's possible to read from outsid its content. from inside you've already mload sload.

Comment: yes, web3.eth.getStorageAt() is what I want ! 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: happy to help, i've reformulated the comment in an answer, if you find it helpfull you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reading stroage from outsi you can use web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, index) for memory i don't think it's possible to read from outsid its content.

[in web3js 1.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getstorageat) documentation :

> getStorageAt web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, position [, defaultBlock]
>   [, callback]) Get the storage at a specific position of an address.

for example :

```
contractAddress = '0x123......'
for (index = 0; index < 10; index++){
 console.log(`[${index}]` + 
   web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, index))
}
```